# Android :: one activity in two tabs?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

> I am working on a Tab Activity. I have one activity as a tab content
>   of one tab. I need to use the same in another tab also.so I have set
>   the a single activity as a two tab content. But when I am running my
>   code . If I am selecting the TAB1 after that I am selecting TAB2.
>   Again I coming back to TAB1. whatever event like entering name in
>   edittext is reflecting in TAB2 not in TAB1.I don't know understand why
>   its happening.

Any Idea? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please post some code to see how you tried to achieve your goal.

Comment: Code? You are using the same intent object for both tabs? Or creating two intents?

Comment: i am creating different intents. using bundle extra flag i am maintaining the tabs.

Comment: you can check the beautiful example provided by android here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html Here they are dealing with one activity with multiple tab

Comment: Nick the example you mentioned is not correct. they are using seperate activity class for each tab.

Comment: Code or more elaboration on what you are trying to get as a result would help. It sounds like you need one activity with two fragments or views which can be swiped back and forth.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned that what you are doing **onTabChanged** ie. whether you are starting that activity again or not.

I think everytime when you are selecting a tab you are staring an Activity.

```
 startActivity(intent);
```

So, whatever change you have made in that activity under **Tab2**, won't reflect on that activity under **Tab1** as you are starting that activity again.

If you are starting that activity everytime **ontabchanged**, then you have to save the changes what you have made under any tab.

As you haven't mentioned clearly what you are doing, so if you are doing something else, let me know.

Comment: No. i am not starting the activity on tabchanged method. i am starting two activitygroup for each tab. in that both activiy group i need to use one activity.

Comment: If you are using same activity, try to check the changed value is being saved or not. I think the changed value is not saved, thats why its not reflecting. I didn't see your code, so without seeing your code its hard to comment more.